# Running command in Selenium firefox container

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver

I am using the docker image selenium/standalone-firefox:114.0, when I try to run a command inside it from my local machine

```bash
docker exec ${container_name} firefox -CreateProfile test
```

I get the following error:

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused 
Error: cannot open display: :99.0
```